Log4Net Could not load file or assembly
Error:
SetUp method failed. SetUp : System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Currently I have log4net version 2.0.7
I want to upgrade to version 2.0.10 which is first without vulnerability but I got above error.
I made research and probably it is cause through library Castle.Core-log4net I use this library in version 4.0.0, in Nuget is indicate that Castle.Core-log4net has dependencies with log4net (>= 2.0.7).
So I can not understand why when I upgrade log4net to 2.0.10 I got error "Could not load file or assembly" if Castle.core.log4net works  with version bigger or equal 2.0.7
What I tried:

In every project in my solution I have correctly version of log4net and path.

In every app.config or web.config I have correct version, public key and bindingRedirect.

Also I tried set in app.config and web.config this configuration showed below because I found this
where is hint that problem could be 3rd party dll but it won't help.


<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.7.0" newVersion="2.0.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

Can anyone could explain why bindingRedirect won't works ?
Edit:
Finally I resolved this problem. It was configuration in file which was used to run tests. When I change configuration everything works fine.

Can you check which version the log4net.dll in the app directory has?

Currently is log4net.2.0.7 because I reverted to this version. I can add once again new version of log4net a I'll check version in packages folder.

I made change and now in package I've version log4net 2.0.7 and 2.0.15 but still I got could not load assembly ....

How can I close this topic ? The problem is resolved.

If you think your solution could help other users, you can answer your own question

Finally I resolved this problem. It was missing configuration in file which was used to run tests. When I change configuration everything works fine.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
